# Texturing a PyOpenGL 3D Cube with PySDL2

Tags: opengl, sdl, python

So, I've just started learning OpenGL with PySDL2, and I've created a class that will create a cube to the window that I've created with PySDL2. What I'd like to do now, is to figure out a way to texture the cube. I don't believe that the actual texturing part is the problem, but actually loading the image. I've tried to do this with PySDL's image loader, but this causes an error from the OpenGL texture creator. Here is my code to load an texture and bind it to OpenGL:

```
def LoadTexture(self, filename):
    """Loads a texture for the cube"""
    surface = SDL_LoadBMP(filename)
    #Checks if the loading succeeded
    if surface:
        #Translate the LP_SDL_Surface-pointer got from SDL_LoadBMP() to a real SDL_Surface
        texture_surface = surface.contents
        texture_format = GL.GL_RGBA
        GL_TEXTURE_ID = GL.glGenTextures(1)
        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_ID)
        GL.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
        GL.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, texture_surface.w, texture_surface.h, 0, texture_format, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_surface)
        return GL_TEXTURE_ID
    return None
```

And the error that gives looks like this:

```
TypeError: ("No array-type handler for type <class 'sdl2.surface.SDL_Surface'> (value: <sdl2.surface.SDL_Surface object at 0x030762B0>) registered", <OpenGL.GL.images.ImageInputConverter object at 0x02EC49F0>)
```

I'm using Python 3 so using something like PIL won't work for me. Any ideas how to get the texture loaded, preferably with PySDL2?

Comment: You should use the 'pixels' member of SDL_surface to get the raw data. see http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryStruct%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLStructTemplate%29 . I can't find any reference on .contents that you are using :|

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixed it. Since the SDL_LoadBMP returns a pointer instead of a proper object, I need to get the proper object from it by calling the .contents member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the 'pixels' member of SDL_surface to get the raw image data. See [SDL_Surface](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryStruct%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLStructTemplate%29).